# How to traverse a complex json in python

Tags: python, json

How do I traverse this json in python? I want to access the markups and apply the html formatting tags in the text based on that. I want to add  tag in the text based on the start and end point provided in the markup.

```
  {
    "content": [{
            "markups": [],
            "contentType": "MEDIA",
            "text": "You will be pleasantly surprised to see snow-capped mountains surrounding you in all directions!",
            "media": {
                "path": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/1*wwvQhdsEA_X4E5GG8JYSsQ.jpeg",
                "mediaType": "IMAGE",
                "height": 2389,
                "width": 5999
            }
        },
        {
            "markups": [],
            "contentType": "TITLE",
            "text": "Uncharted territories: Parvati Valley, Kalga, Kheerganga Trek"
        },
        {
            "markups": [{
                "type": "ITALICS",
                "start": 134,
                "end": 145
            }],
            "contentType": "BODY",
            "text": "If you have never wandered in the woods"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For starters, this is not valid JSON. Once it is, you can deserialize the json using `json.loads()`

Comment: I think some brackets are missing

Comment: I have updated the json. please let me know how to add <i> tag based on the markups provided in json.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided is not valid.

A valid JSON string can be converted into nested dictionaries as follows:

```
import json

json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: Additional question is how to traverse it efficiently.

Comment: updated the json. the important thing is how to add the tags in the text based on the markups.